# MAC address is removed with tainted VirtualBox modules on Fedora 29

Tags: fedora, kernel, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I am getting crash reports. `net/mac80211/driver-ops` results in `drv_remove_interface`. My network interface is removed and I can't connect to the WiFi.
I can recover this by shutting down or going in and out of flight mode. It looks like it crashes once I unsuspend it.

I can't report this. My kernel is tainted. It's VirtualBox modules: `vboxpci`, `vboxnetadp`, `vboxnetfit` and `vboxdrv`.

- Is VirtualBox causing the issue or is it just restricting me from sending the report?
- Do I need to reinstall VirtualBox after the upgrade?
- Is there a bug in Fedora with VirtualBox and the network interface?
- Is this message misleading and completely unrelated to VirtualBox?

---

Regardless, I uninstalled it. As most sites referred to the removal in lower case, I just want to highlight that it is title case in Fedora.

```
sudo dnf remove VirtualBox-5.2.24-1.fc29.x86_64
sudo dnf remove VirtualBox-kmodsrc-5.2.24-1.fc29.noarch
sudo dnf remove VirtualBox-server-5.2.24-1.fc29.x86_64
sudo dnf remove virtualbox-guest-additions-5.2.24-1.fc29.x86_64
```

Comment: If you do not have a specific use for VirtualBox (such as bridging wireless without masquerading or something), you might could give QEMU/KVM a shot, perhaps with one of several front-ends.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I will look into that as an alternative.